# Что делать, выдаёт ошибку при запуске дискорд бота на python3

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image: изображение]
Что делать, выдаёт ошибку при запуске дискорд бота на python3

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Improper token has been passed - буквально "был передан неправильный токен". Не знаю что еще пояснять.

Comment: Пожалуйста скиньте код без токена